# Nicely formatted source code

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

The source code is already formatted using newline characters and whitespace.

Goals:

1. keep source formatting as long as lines fit in the screen horizontally (e.g. pre)

   - show line numbers on the left side aligned with the lines (e.g. a table with line numbers in a separate column)
   - break lines into multiple lines when they do not fit in the screen (e.g. doable with white-space: pre-wrap)
   - never merge whitespace or newline characters (e.g. pre does that)
   - for lines that break either show the line number multiple times or just once at the top (e.g. align the line numbers top)
   - for lines that break show a small marker image at the end and/or at the beginning (e.g. use background image per line, but for that I need to make the pre elements separate)
   - allow selecting and copy/pasting a couple of lines with the mouse without including the line numbers (e.g. a single pre gives this, but otherwise this seems to be impossible)
   - outputting HTML and CSS from the server-side, but preferrably without JavaScript

I can't make it supporting all the above points, seems like it's impossible. I tried using div, table, pre in various combinations, with `white-space: pre-wrap` and so on, but had no luck having all the options.

What's a simple solution?

Comment: Can we see some of the css, and an example of the html?

Comment: I posted some trials as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ordered list does a decent job. Opera doesn't copy the line numbers with it, but I think other browsers might do.

Comment: Chrome looks like it selects the line numbers in an ordered list, but doesn't include them when copying.

Comment: Hmm, ol/li looks almost right, but not in all ff, chrome, opera, ie... bah

Do you know what is the standard behavior (from the spec) wrt. copying or not copying the numbers?

Comment: No, sorry. The main difference between Opera and Firefox wrt. copying is that Firefox copies the formatting (bold, italic etc but also including lists), whereas Opera only copies in plain text. That may have something to do with it.

Comment: Also, Chrome *does* copy the line numbers when pasting as rich text (i.e. into Word), but doesn't when pasting as plain text (i.e. into Notepad).

Answer (score 0):

Here are my trials, but none of this does what I want:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
      <pre style="margin: 0px; -moz-user-select: none;"><img src="eol.png"/></pre>
    </td>
    <td style="background-image: url('eol.png'); background-position: right top; background-repeat: repeat-y;">
      <pre style="white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0px;">This is a        long text         having weird whitespace content that has to be word wrapped even though</pre>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
      <pre style="margin: 0px; -moz-user-select: none;"><img src="eol.png"/></pre>
    </td>
    <td>
      <pre style="white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0px;">it is preformatted.</pre>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <pre style="float: left; margin: 0px;">1 </pre>
      <pre style="white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0px;">This is a        long text         having weird whitespace content that has to be word wrapped even though</pre>
    </div>
    <div>
      <pre style="float: left; margin: 0px;">2 </pre>
      <pre style="white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0px;">it is preformatted.</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap">The Server runs under the Ubuntu Linux Server Edition (x86-64) operating system. Installing the Server under other versions of Ubuntu Linux (such as th     e Desktop Edition) should not be a problem.
```

Installing the Server under other Linux distributions may be different and may need more hand tuning th      an what is described here. Other operating systems such as Windows, Mac OS X, etc. are not tested and most likely will not work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl.  [Javascript code prettifier](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html)  I know you mentioned no javascript, but unless you do it server side, I'm not sure how you are going to avoid it.  What language are you trying to format?

Comment: And it's not about pretty printing, I already have that at the server side. It's just that the client side rendering is not as good as it could be.

Answer (score 0):

1. Give style to the code using highlight_string()
2. Explode / break the text by line
3. Add the number of line at the start of each line using `<input type="text" value="# of line" disable>`

Something like:

```
$file = highlight_string(file_get_contents("some_code.php"),true);
$file = explode("<br />",$file);

foreach ($file as $n=>&$line)
    $line = "<input type='text' disabled='disabled' value='$n' />".$line;

echo join("<br />",$file);
```