# CSS/JS to format and display code samples on a website

Tags: javascript, css, open-source, web

I'm looking for a set of CSS/JS code that would let me create special text areas with properly formatted and displayed code samples similar to [this](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/837719-css-js-format-display-code-samples-website).

Would you please suggest a open source solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751509/nicely-formatted-source-code) may be of help.  You might also want to check out [code-highlighter](https://github.com/danwrong/code-highlighter).  It highlights JavaScript, CSS, and HTML by default, but doesn't have line numbers.  [Here is an interesting solution](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/how_to_style_a_code_listing.asp) that does have line numbers.

Also, [google-code-prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) looks like a fairly mature and has pretty good support for a number of languages.

Answer (score 3):

SyntaxHighlighter
version 2.1.364 (October 15 2009)
http://alexgorbatchev.com

http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/examples/size for a demo