# how to write script like a string on my view?

Tags: jquery

i use this syntax to write a string on my view by jquery:

```
 $(".temp_class").append('<p>my name</p>')
```

and it show: my name but when i use this :

```
$(".temp_class").append('<script type="text/javascript">alert("s");</script>')
```

it brings up a alert dialog bow how can i handle it to write this like a string not HTML tag to prevent alert dialog box.

i do not want write HTML tags i want to show it like a string

Comment: Do you want to display HTML tags as well?

Comment: i edited,but it bring up a alert dialogbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also trylike this

```
var str= "<script>alert('hi!');</script>";
var escaped = $(".temp_class").text(str).html();
```

---

that means you need to do like this which use prototype function

```
var script = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("s");</script>'.escapeHTML();
$(".temp_class").append(script);
```

check for prototype : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_string_escapehtml.htm

---

you need to format your string properly like this , so this will display `<b>Availability</b>`

```
$mytext = "&lt;b&gt;Availability:&lt;/b&gt"
$(".temp_class").append($mytext);
```

Comment: what about '>' character,it will replace with what?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity you can encapsulate code string with `<pre><code>` tags. You can use a code prettify plugin like below.
[CSS/JS to format and display code samples on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688484/css-js-to-format-and-display-code-samples-on-a-website)

http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Comment: Just posting the links?  what for? could you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Firs, you miss the open `<`.
But you just need to show an alert after the trigger. You dont have to put the alert inside your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the code in `<pre></pre>`

In your case it is:

```
$(".temp_class").append('<pre><script type="text/javascript">alert("s");</script></pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$(".temp_class").append('<script type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
$(".temp_class").find('script').append('alert("s");');
```

#### [Demo @ jsbin](http://jsbin.com/IYakoFuG/1/edit)

As this is dynamically done you have to look it in the source with inspector/firebug.

or if you want to put it as a string then `.text()` will do it:

```
$(".temp_class").text('<script type="text/javascript">alert("s");<\/script>');
```

Comment: He wants to append not replace

Comment: @sash yes it seems to be, i think this is what OP needs.